# How to use wildcard field in Aiven's ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aiven

I wanted to test the new [wildcard field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type) in my ElasticSearch instance ([Aiven](https://aiven.io/elasticsearch)).

I've tried this:

```json
PUT /wildcard_test
{
  "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "wildcard_field" : {
          "type" : "wildcard"
          }
        }
  }
}
```

And I'm getting this response:

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "No handler for type [wildcard] declared on field [wildcard_field]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No handler for type [wildcard] declared on field [wildcard_field]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "No handler for type [wildcard] declared on field [wildcard_field]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Here are the info regarding the instance:

GET /

```json
{
  "name" : "...",
  "cluster_name" : "...",
  "cluster_uuid" : "...",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.3",
    "build_flavor" : "unknown",
    "build_type" : "unknown",
    "build_hash" : "c4138e51121ef06a6404866cddc601906fe5c868",
    "build_date" : "2020-10-16T10:36:16.141335Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.6.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

GET /_license

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "invalid_index_name_exception",
        "reason" : "Invalid index name [_license], must not start with '_'.",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "_license"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "invalid_index_name_exception",
    "reason" : "Invalid index name [_license], must not start with '_'.",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "_license"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

My understanding is that this feature is provided by X-Pack, which I don't whether or not is included in Aiven's service. Is there some way to make this work?

Comment: I suppose the [`_license` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-license.html) is blocked in Aiven but that shouldn't prevent you from creating an index and searching it. What have you tried so far in that regard? The question content doesn't correspond to its title.

Comment: @JoeSorocin please check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `wildcard` field type was indeed [added in v7.9](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/49993), it's (unfortunately) only available as part of an [X-Pack subscription](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) and I presume the one running on Aiven is OSS which is missing this and other X-Pack features.

Comment: I've been in this page before (it redirects to a localized version), but I didn't recognize the part that said about wildcards in my own language. Thanks for the answer, I think I'll have to work with other alternatives then.